# Get json array value with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

i started to learn json and ajax and i have this json file:

```
{
  "data": {
    "children": [{
      "data": {
        "domain": "some.url.com"
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "domain": "another.url.com"
        }
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

How i get the first `domain` from this file?

I try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON("https://myurl.com/api.json", function(data){
    console.log(data.children[0].data.domain);
});
});
```

and it didn't work :(

Comment: Tipp: open devtools and you 'console.log(data)' to display the data..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look closely on your data and your code.

You've got `data` variable, then `data` object with `children` array so you can access it like that

```
data.data.children[0].data.domain
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.getJSON("https://myurl.com/api.json", function(data){
   console.log(data.data.children[0].data.domain);
   });
 });
```